# Is $f(x) = \exp(-|x|)$ in the Schwartz space?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, convergence-divergence, schwartz-space

If I have a function given as $f(x) = \exp(-|x|)$, is this function in the Schwartz space?

As a common example of the Schwartz function is considered $ e^{x^2}$. But in my example I got a absolute value, so the integral in $\Bbb R$ converges. The Schwartz function are functions such that they decrease rapidly in the infinity, so do they derivatives.

Well If I try to take a derivative from my given function, I got $\operatorname{sign}(x)*\exp(-|x|)$, and so on. But it doesn't seem to be a rapid decrease. Is there any general way how to test any function, if it is in Schwartz space?

Comment: No: they are not smooth at the origin.

Comment: Oh, that's true, so everytime, I got a function which derivative contains a signum function, I do not have the smoothnes, hence the function isn't there? Is this a correct assumption?

Comment: Looks like it.  Why don't you recite the definition of the  Schwartz space in your problem statement.  What you've currently got is a partial description.

Comment: Ok, I will edit it soon.

Comment: $\exp(-|x|^2)$ is Schwartz so you must be careful